# Join with json column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need find rows in table `users` by joining column in table `queries`.

I wrote some sql but it takes 0.200s to run, when `SELECT * FROM ...` takes 0.80s.

How can I improve performance?

[db-fiddle example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uTRVjcn7tGL49GHYxniC6U/1)

The tables are :

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id INT,
  browser varchar
);

CREATE TABLE queries (
  id INT,
  settings jsonb
);

INSERT INTO users (id,browser) VALUES (1, 'yandex');
INSERT INTO users (id, browser) VALUES (2, 'google');
INSERT INTO users (id, browser) VALUES (3, 'google');

INSERT INTO queries (id, settings) VALUES (1, '{"browser":["Yandex", "TestBrowser"]}');
```

and the query :

```
select x2.id as user_id, x1.id as query_id

 FROM (
   SELECT id, json_array_elements_text((settings->>'browser')::JSON) browser 
   FROM queries) x1

JOIN users x2 ON lower(x1.browser::varchar) = lower(x2.browser::varchar) 
group by 1,2;
```

Comment: Do you really need group by? If you omit it you have performance benefit

Comment: @apomene this works as DISTINCT in that query. The real performance killer is using `lower` and joining on the JSON result. `lower` prevents the server from using indexes on the columns

Comment: @apomene Yea. That's just example, but in real database, i guess, i need it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos can you please provide example at db-fiddle?

Comment: @Uebanchik in any case, what you need to do on the JSON side is to check whether a string appears in an array, not extract the elements themselves. You can do that with `?`.  This can take advantage of [JSONB indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING). On the other hand, a plain-old many-to-many table linking browsers and queries could be a lot simpler and faster

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos emm... Sorry? There is a link to an example in the question. It has a database, and an example query...

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yea, i know about '?', but i dont know how i can use it with joins..

Comment: The *real* solution is to use a proper many-to-many table.  You've already seen that using JSON instead of a proper table isn't a great idea. You could use `ON x1.settings::jsonb->'browser' ? x2.browser` but *JSON* is case sensitive and `"Yandex"` isn't the same as `"yandex"`. You're repeating the same strings too, when you could store just the IDs to a `browsers` table

Comment: I doesn't take nearly that long with the data you show.  Since we don't have access to your real data, please show us the output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`.  See https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Comment: +1 on using a many-to-many. If you aren't going that way, your documentation should include a very clear explanation as to why you're using a more complicated strategy. Namely, packing everything into a blob that you then need to pull bits out of to get your work done. Sometimes, there's a solid case for that...often that's more cultural/contextual than technical. But it's worth noting in your code as it's not obvious otherwise. At least not to RDBMS people.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> json_array_elements_text((settings->>'browser')::JSON)
> ```

'->>' converts the result to text.  Then you cast it back to JSON. Doing that on one row (if you only have one) is not really going to be a problem, but it is rather pointless.

You could instead do:

```
jsonb_array_elements_text(settings->'browser')
```

> ```
> ON lower(x1.browser::varchar) = lower(x2.browser::varchar)
> ```

You can create an index that can be used for this:

```
create index on users (lower(browser));
```

It won't do much good on a table with 3 rows.  But presumably you don't really have 3 rows.